# Bug: Gold and Bronze icons for rep backwards

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-completed

The gold and bronze icons for rep in regards to the user appear to be backwards VS what is petitioned on the site design.

Comment: You could also add that only two are visible here, if you look at your name, gramps

Comment: I dont think gold was given in meta.

Comment: aaaha! I withdraw the point.

Comment: ... but could we asked to have them filled ?

Comment: I would prefer that, too since they only show up in the header and not in the profile or badges area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed a fix to our dev server. also updated the badge visuals. instead of outlined, they're now filled for better readability. The changes will go live after our next production build.